# Calculate required funds for truffle migrate to live network

Tags: truffle, gas, truffle-migration

Trying to deploy a dapp to the live network. Got this insufficient funds for gas * price + value:

[image]

My wallet currently has 0.05 ether... How do I calculate the required funds?

Comment: I'd use ganache it has a block explorer where you can inspect transactions and gas used, then the formula is using the formula indicated in the error message. The gas price used by default is the median from the most recent blocks, you can use https://ethgasstation.info/ to choose a different value.

Comment: so the `gas used` that i see in ganache for every transaction is a static figure that will be identical when i deploy the same code to the live network?

Comment: Yes, if you repeat deployment with exactly the same contrats the gas used should be identical for every network.

Comment: dude you can add this as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use ganache, it has a block explorer where you can inspect transactions and gas used. The gas used is independent of the network used, gas used for deployment should be the same in mainnet than in a testnet.

Then you can use the formula indicated in the error message.

> gas * price + value

The gas price used by default is the median from the most recent blocks, you can use `web3.eth.gasPrice` to obtain the mosts recent price.

This is dynamic value so it will change frequently. You can use a service like http://ethgasstation.info to obtain fixed value and use that value in your truffle.js file.

From the [Truffle documentation](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration)

```
networks: {
  // ..
  live: {
    network_id: 1,        // Ethereum public network
    // optional config values:
    // gas
    // gasPrice
  }
}
```

Comment: What would the +value be?

Comment: @JosephLee It's the amount of ether you are transferring, it's could be zero.